# How to stream video frames into Sagemaker endpoint on AWS in real-time

Tags: sockets, socket.io, amazon-sagemaker, flask-socketio

It is easy to invoke the Sagemaker endpoint while sending one image at the time or the batch of images with one invocation. I've done it and it works great. Example is below. However the problem I am facing is different and I described it below.

```
self.session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
        )
        client = self.session.client('runtime.sagemaker', region_name='us-east-1', config=CONFIG)
        response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                              ContentType='application/json',
                                              Body=json.dumps(payload))
```

Sagemaker's session has a hard-set timeout, therefore you can't keep the connection open to stream images (video frames) into it for inference and receive the stream of responses back. Also I could not find the way to run a socket in my container on Sagemaker and keep the port open, to minimize the latency. Again because of the timeout, and it wouldn't even connect to the socket endpoint, while regular Flask Restful API endpoints receive calls absolutely fine.

Question is: "Is there a way to stream images into the Sagemaker endpoint? I keep on reading online, that there is so called Real-Time Inference in place in the Sagemaker. However it is only for invoking endpoint with a single input or a batch. I have a live video feed and I need to stream frames as they come in and receive the stream of response back and be able to do it through something alike socket with an open port. Is Sagemaker even suitable for something like that?"

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely utilize SageMaker Inference for video streams. An option that might make more sense for your use-case is an Asynchronous Inference Endpoint. With this option you can queue requests (in your case frames) and poll your endpoint for responses. This is a near real-time latency based option and the only difference in invocation itself is that you point to an S3 path with your data. Here is an example of working with video data and Async Inference: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-inference-computer-vision/tree/main.